# How to uninstall AQtime 8

Tags: delphi, aqtime

I installed AQtime standard when I had Delphi 10 installed but have since upgraded to Delphi 10.4.

I decided to clean up my system to free up some SSD space and uninstall AQtime 8 but it wont let me.

When I try running the uninstaller from programs and features it just says "There is no compatible version of Delphi installed" and refuses to uninstall.

My OS is Windows 10.

Any ideas?

Comment: Contact AQtime support.

Comment: @fpietta tried that, they don't support AQtime standard only pro.

Comment: Could try installing the latest version of AQTime Standard which is 8.81 available via GetIt in Delphi 10.4.2. See if it updates the old install and then lets you uninstalling after that.